# Knockout load JSON from AJAX call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, knockout.js, filter, pagination

I'm currently creating a list of items with pager and filter.
The base I used is this: http://jsfiddle.net/JTimperley/pyCTN/13/

But I need to load the data from AJAX, and the response is JSON.

The model which recieves the data on creation:

```
function CustomerPageModel(data)
{
  if (!data)
  {
    data = {};
  }

  var self = this;
  self.customers = ExtractModels(self, data.customers, CustomerModel);

  var filters = [
    {
      Type: "text",
      Name: "Name",
      Value: ko.observable(""),
      RecordValue: function(record) { return record.name; }
    },
    {
      Type: "select",
      Name: "Status",
      Options: [
        GetOption("All", "All", null),
        GetOption("None", "None", "None"),
        GetOption("New", "New", "New"),
        GetOption("Recently Modified", "Recently Modified", "Recently Modified")
      ],
      CurrentOption: ko.observable(),
      RecordValue: function(record) { return record.status; }
    }
  ];
  var sortOptions = [
    {
      Name: "ID",
      Value: "ID",
      Sort: function(left, right) { return left.id < right.id; }
    },
    {
      Name: "Name",
      Value: "Name",
      Sort: function(left, right) { return CompareCaseInsensitive(left.name, right.name); }
    },
    {
      Name: "Status",
      Value: "Status",
      Sort: function(left, right) { return CompareCaseInsensitive(left.status, right.status); }
    }
  ];
  self.filter = new FilterModel(filters, self.customers);
  self.sorter = new SorterModel(sortOptions, self.filter.filteredRecords);
  self.pager = new PagerModel(self.sorter.orderedRecords);
}
```

The binding works well if I simply echo json value for `events`
However, when I call my AJAX-function and new data is added, the model won't update.

```
var data = {
  action: 'load_data'
};
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);
  var models = ExtractModels(_customerPageModel, json, CustomerModel);
  _customerPageModel.customers = models;
});
```

Comment: `self.customers ` declare it a observableArray and map your data from server to it. As customers is observableArray view will be update and so on . Right now i cant see that as observableArray(quite a long code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are **replacing** the `_customerPageModel.customers` variable.

Knockout data-binding works by using some special properties - `observables` and `observableArray`s.

Anything that you need to be bound to the DOM must be observable.

Therefore, you should probably transform your `customers` into a observableArray, and push to it when you have new data. For example:

```
function CustomerPageModel(data)
{
  (...)    
  var self = this;
  self.customers = ko.observableArray(ExtractModels(self, data.customers, CustomerModel));
  (...)
}
```

And when receiving data:

```
var data = {
  action: 'load_data'
};
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);
  var models = ExtractModels(_customerPageModel, json, CustomerModel);
  _customerPageModel.customers.push.apply(_customerPageModel.customers, models);
});
```

Take a look at the observableArray docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Note that I am using the `push` method to add all new data to the end of the array. You may wish to completely overwrite the array. If so, it's even simpler:

```
_customerPageModel.customers(models);
```

In this way, your `customers` array is replaced by the new `models` array.

Comment: Do you know how to update the Pager as well? I've tried multiple solutions now without any success. :(

Comment: You can propably add an `update` method to `PagerModel` and call it with new data.

Comment: Hmm, no matter what I do the PagerModel and FilterModel won't recalculate any computed -> which means that they always have 0 items.

Tried by adding dummy observables inside, and notifySubsribers but with no luck. Are there any other way to trigger computed to run again?

Comment: @Henric please post another question with a specific fiddle to your new problem :) it will be easier to help

Comment: Hi, I created a new question with more information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085495/knockout-load-ajax-to-filter-pager
Thanks :)